# Web Scraping Daily Interest Rates Using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape rates from the below link using python.

https://www.mufap.com.pk/industry.php?tab=03

However, when I try the pandas library, I can't find any tables.

Help please.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_html(r"https://www.mufap.com.pk/industry.php?tab=03")
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

Comment: yes, you are trying to obtain tables but there is no table on the site you posted. try to take a look at the tables first.

Comment: The problem is that I have a main link (the one posted above, which contains the link to the respective years) then when I click on the link it opens up the page to daily rates, which Im trying to get.

Comment: The PKRV Rates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to use `beautifulsoup` + `pandas` to load the CSV files into a dataframes:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.mufap.com.pk/industry.php?tab=03"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

years = [
    f"https://www.mufap.com.pk/{year['href']}"
    for year in soup.select("#waqar-daily-prices a")
]

year_2023 = years[0]
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(year_2023).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a:-soup-contains("PKRV")[href*="csv"]'):
    print(a['href'])
    df = pd.read_csv(a['href'], encoding_errors='ignore')
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...

https://mufap.com.pk/pdf/PKRVs/2023/Feb/PKRV28022023.csv                                                 
   Tenor  Mid Rate  Change                        
0     1W     17.41    0.16                                                                               
1     2W     17.56    0.03                
2     1M     18.74    0.23                                                                               
3     2M     19.37    0.25          
4     3M     19.53    0.18                                                                               
5     4M     19.75    0.07                                                                               
6     6M     19.82    0.02                                                                               
7     9M     19.89    0.03
8     1Y     19.93    0.00                                                                               
9     2Y     18.31    0.02                                                                               
10    3Y     18.17    0.01                                                                               
11    4Y     15.95   -0.04                                                                               
12    5Y     15.80   -0.08                                                                               
13    6Y     15.79   -0.03                                                                               
14    7Y     15.75    0.00                                                                               
15    8Y     15.59    0.00                                                                               
16    9Y     15.50   -0.01                                                                               
17   10Y     15.46    0.00                                                                               
18   15Y     15.27    0.01                                                                               
19   20Y     15.25    0.00
https://mufap.com.pk/pdf/PKRVs/2023/Feb/PKRV27022023.csv                                                 
   Tenor  Mid Rate  Change
0     1W     17.25   -0.12                                                                               
1     2W     17.53    0.05                                                                               
2     1M     18.51   -0.01                                                                               
3     2M     19.12   -0.02              

...
```